# AD4610 - Is it possible to eleminate this single overshoot

Tags: operational-amplifier, stability, ringing, compensation

I am trying to compensate input capacitance of the AD4610. It does not matter if it is actually over- or undershooting - there is always a spike:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I do not have this problem with the OPA4141 for example:
[image]

Is it possible to eliminate this single spike?

Comment: What is the difference between pictures #1 and #2? Probe compensation?

Comment: Not the probe. The capacitance of the compensation circuit of the tested opamp.

Comment: If you read the datasheet graphs carefully, your results may be consistent with a 30pF probe load for both. It depends on gain, inverting or not and load capacitance. Your schematic  and layout would reveal more.  I would hope you are using the non-inverting configuration.  I suspect the AD4610 uses MOSFET outputs, while the OPA4141 uses BJT common emitter complementary outputs unlike most BJT type that use Darlington COmmon Collector outputs that are not rail to rail. SO output impedance of each OP AMP is quite different 1~10 MHz.

Comment: Yes, it is not inverting

Comment: The OPA4141 is critically damped in non-inverting mode while well overdamped in the inverting mode.  The AD4610  is underdamped in non-inverting mode but not sure in inverting mode.  It cannot handle large C loads without a 50 Ohm series R.

Comment: The AD4610 has a higher GBW with low capacitance, much higher current limit and well compensated for most applications.  This is not one of them for a text-book step response with no info your layout inductance or stray load impedances in your question or probe ground return length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spike in waveform originates from a peak in AD4610 at approximately 2 MHz (from what I gather on scope trace). Thus the transient response results in overshooting, aka "ringing". The other OPA apparently have a fairly flat frequency response and has optimal damping on step function.

I doubt very much that the overshot can be fixed by simple capacitive compensation. You need to SPICE model this OPA with all board parasitics and find a more complicated compensation to remove the 2-MHz resonance and make the frequency response function flat if you don't like the small overshot.

It even might be impossible at all, since even the original manufacurers datasheet shows exactly the same kind of large amplitude response:

[image]

Comment: Actually, I am not even sure if my answer is correct :-(. It conflates "small signal" response with "large signal response". The small-signal response might be flat, per specifications it is. But large signals behave differently, some internal nodes likely saturate dynamically, resulting in overshoot. In any case it will be difficult to fix that by external component selection...

Comment: Thank you. I have decided to use 4141. Actually I try to find something better in this price 'RR jfet input but the selection is quite limited  (price matters as well)